# TIM0_OVF on atmel studio 7 doesn't work

Tags: atmega

Excuse-me for my English.
I'm beginner program in assembler language with atmel studio 7. 
I try to blank led on port c every 500ms with atmega8.At simulation, 
I don't see the Time overflow execution. Where is my mistake?

### ---

.DEF    mp = R16

.DEF    mp1 = R17

.DEF    vard = R18

;Registers

RJMP   RESET
RETI

RETI

RETI

RETI

RJMP TIM0_OVF

RETI

RETI

RETI

RESET:

LDI mp,0x04

OUT SPH,mp

LDI mp,0x5F

OUT SPL,mp

;Stack initialization

LDI mp,0x01

OUT DDRC,mp

LDI mp,0x00

OUT PORTC,mp

;Choose a port c as output

LDI mp,0b00000101

OUT TCCR0,mp

;Prescaler Fclk/1024

LDI mp,246

OUT TCNT0,mp

LDI mp,0b00000001

OUT TIMSK,mp

;Timer/counter0

LDI vard,50

;variable vard to count (50*10*1.024ms=500ms)

```
SEI
```

;Activation interrupt for SREG

MAIN_LOOP:

CPI vard,0

BRNE NEXT01

;If I'm here, this means, 500ms are passed

LDI vard,50

;initialization of vard
IN  mp,PINC

;read port c
LDI mp1,0b00000001

EOR mp,mp1
; complemente for port c

OUT PORTC,mp

NEXT01:

; If 500ms aren't passed, I continue to verify with main loop

RJMP MAIN_LOOP

TIM0_OVF:

```
IN mp,SREG

PUSH mp
```

;In case of  overflow,Imust save data from SREG in stack

```
DEC vard
```

;Decrement vard

```
LDI mp,246

OUT TCNT0,mp
```

;Initializate TCNT0

`POP mp

OUT SREG,mp

RETI`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been abandoned by an asker who made no effort to follow up or clarify

Answer (score 0):

No comments or anything?
Well, one thing is for sure. It's not TIMO but TIM0 .. which stands for Timer0 (as in zero, null).

Yet, ASM is so hard to debug and even more without any comments so probably this won't help you. Plus, I don't see any configuration of the TCCR registers so please, comment your code (and format it accordingly)

Comment: Thank you. I have problem to edit the text here. I don't know how can I do it. I have copy source code and paste it here, but only a start of the text is appeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2486-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8_L_datasheet.pdf), page 46, you can see interrupt vectors list of your MCU. The timer0 overflow vector is at the address 0x09. But according to the code you have shown, your `RJMP TIM0_OVF` instruction is located at the address 0x05, which would be target for `TIMER1_CAPT` interrupt instead. Actually, timer0 interrupt is jumping directly to the `RESET` label in your code.

Side note: your code is bit "dirty" in some other aspects, but nothing of these should affect just this piece you have shown.